# Telerik report designer using store procedure return multiple data sets how to access all data sets. report shows only top dataset result

Tags: crystal-reports, telerik, telerik-reporting

We have started exploring Telerik report. at present we are using SSRS.
in Telerik report we notice when using progress Telerik report designer i.e teleri standalone report designer app when we pass stored procedure as data source and that stored procedure returning more then one data set only Top 1 data set result will be visible in Telerik report designing app.

I am attaching screen short below :

1. from SP
   [image]
2. from Telerik Report Design app
   [image]

As can be seen from both above screen short Telerik Report design app shows only one dataset under Datasource1 whereas SP send two dataset.

How can i get both dataset in Telerik report design ??